# mat-menu-item in the same size as mat-menu button? (Angular Material v.12)

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I want make the mat-menu-item button in the same size as mat-menu

Example:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XmYz.png)

```html
<div class="container d-block d-md-none">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="w-75">
        Descobrir
      </button>
      <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>Descobrir</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Navegar</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Lista de Desejos</button>
      </mat-menu>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Created a stackblitz for you - adjust the width to your liking, but they should be the same for both the button and the menu container:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyfb4q?file=src/styles.scss

Styling:

```
.my-button {
  width: 280px;
}

.mat-menu-panel.my-menu {
  width: 280px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="my-button" color="primary" mat-flat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
  Menu button
</button>
<mat-menu class="my-menu" #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item disabled>
    <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
    <span>Check voice mail</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
    <span>Disable alerts</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```